Is this puzzle solvable? Choose 6 five-letter words to get maximum score
I'm trying to avoid any disrespectful self promotion. However, a friend came up with a neat daily 5 letter word game (similar to Wordle and that style of game), I helped him code it into a playable web game.
The maximum score in the game is 25 points. You must provide 6 five letter words and each word locks a letter position of the word below it. Locked letters cannot be reused. Each unique letter is worth 1 point, the assigned letter (the letter locked from the previous word) is worth zero. The problem is that neither of us believe a perfect score is possible, even if you get to choose the letter locking spots, and the starting letter.
Given the less restrictive rules of choosing your own locked letter, can a perfect score be achieved with common language words?
Example Game: Bold letters are "locked" from word above.












A
F
T
E
R


C
H
O
I
R


S
L
A
I
N


M
A
V
E
N


P
A
V
E
S


B
A
G
G
Y



In this example game I've reused several letters, and the total unique letters (ABCEFGHILMNOPRSTVY) give me a score of 18. Is a perfect game possible?

"Locked letters cannot be reused." - What exactly does this mean?  Does it mean that I cannot use an F ever after the initial word "AFTER"?

How is 25 (the best possible score) achieved if each guess is a maximum of 4 points?  6 x 4 = 24

@LeppyR64 for here the locked letters bit doesn't matter as to get maximum score you have to use a new letter everytime. 25 is max as the first guess is 5 new letters, and then each guess after gives 4 new letters

Can you clarify what "common language" dictionary you'd accept? This would help people who write programs for computer-assisted search, and prevent arguments over whether any given word is common enough.

I believe the confusion stems from the fact that the first word has a locked letter - if every word has a locked letter that doesn't score, then 24 points is optimal, although 25 distinct letters are possible (as shown).

If you redid this with 5 six-letter words, then a score of 26 might theoretically be possible.  I wonder if it's worth trying?

@DarrelHoffman I have an answer if you want to open a new question.

@RobPratt I don't want to steal the OP's thunder on this.  I'd suggest that he make the new question if he wants.  (I assume you just modified your code from your answer below for this?)

@DarrelHoffman Yes, your assumption is correct.

This wasn't tagged [tag:no-computers] which would make it fiendishly hard (IMO).

Equivalently stated: "Find a chain of 6 5-letter words using 25 unique letters. First word uses 5 distinct letters; each of the last 5 words uses 4 new unique letters and shares exactly one common letter in the same position as its predecessor"

To modify and make it insanely hard, require the column position of the locked letters to also be unique, between rows. All three solutions have at least one repetition in column position.

@smci It cannot be done with the 2315 common words.

@RobPratt: uhuh. can anyone do it using 1 as a one of the lock positions? and 4 distinct lock values?

@smci See my updated answer.

@RobPratt: FYI the Wordle dictionaries contain 12,966 words: 10,657 additional guesswords. And TWL and SOWPODS lists are larger still. There's also 2of12 list. Some allow proper names and/or trademarks. The question didn't say which dictionary, but it did say "with common language words?"

@smci Yes, an earlier comment requested clarification on common.  I am able to do what you want by using uncommon words.


  JUNKS
     |
 FOXES
    |
 WAVED
  |
 MARCH
     |
 GLYPH
  |
 BLITZ



Very nice, +1 all common english words with nothing super obscure too

Very impressive! I am surprised Q was the letter left out! Thanks for proving it is possible.

I started the problem under the impression that vowels would be hard to come by, and so Q felt like the logical letter to ignore for a common-word solution. Only later would I realize that locking vowels would make that less of an issue.

@BeastlyGerbil Note that junk as in trash is only a noun and has no plural of junks, so this is junk as a type of boat with plural junks. Blitz is a German word, used in English only in some very specific context like Blitzkrieg.

@quarague Junk is also a verb meaning to toss aside or get rid of (derived from the noun referring to trash), and while blitz is a German loan word, it has an array of other uses outside of the Blitz (e.g., when you blitz something in a food processor or blitz a player on the other team). Both are perfectly normal, everyday words.

Impressive, did you use a computer? which algorithm? which lexicon?

Also, in this the column position of the locked letters is 5,4,2,5,2 (two repetitions). To make it insanely hard, require the column position of the locked letters to also be unique!

@smci I had a list of one-vowel words open while trying different combinations, but ended up using very little of it.

Here's one that omits only X, obtained via integer linear programming:


BROWN
 |
FRITZ
  |
GLIDE
    |
SHAVE
  |
QUACK
 |
JUMPY


For the 2315 common words from the list provided in What is the longest Wordle game?, the possible choices for the omitted letter turn out to be B, F, J, M, Q, S, V, X, and Z.  The other choices for the omitted letters each yield a maximum of 24.

By request, here is SAS code:
proc optmodel;
   /* declare parameters and read data */
   set <str> WORDS;
   read data words into WORDS=[word];
   set LETTERS = setof {k in 65..65+26-1} byte(k);
   num numPositions = 5;
   set POSITIONS = 1..numPositions;
   set <str> WORDS_l_p {LETTERS, POSITIONS} init {};
   str letterThis;
   for {w in WORDS} do;
      for {p in 1..length(w)} do;
         letterThis = char(w,p);
         WORDS_l_p[letterThis,p] = WORDS_l_p[letterThis,p] union {w};
      end;
   end;
   num numSteps = 6;
   set STEPS = 1..numSteps;

   /* declare variables */
   var AssignWord {WORDS, STEPS} binary;
   var AssignLetter {LETTERS, STEPS, POSITIONS} binary;
   var UseLetter {LETTERS} binary;
   var IsLocked {LETTERS, STEPS diff {1}, POSITIONS} binary;

   /* declare objective */
   max NumUsedLetters = sum {l in LETTERS} UseLetter[l];

   /* declare constraints */
   con OneWordPerStep {s in STEPS}:
      sum {w in WORDS} AssignWord[w,s] = 1;
   con WordImpliesLetter {l in LETTERS, s in STEPS, p in POSITIONS}:
      sum {w in WORDS_l_p[l,p]} AssignWord[w,s] = AssignLetter[l,s,p];
   con UseLetterImpliesAssignLetter {l in LETTERS}:
      UseLetter[l] <= sum {s in STEPS, p in POSITIONS} AssignLetter[l,s,p];
   con OneLockedPerStep {s in STEPS diff {1}}:
      sum {l in LETTERS, p in POSITIONS} IsLocked[l,s,p] = 1;
   con LockedThis {l in LETTERS, s in STEPS diff {1}, p in POSITIONS}:
      IsLocked[l,s,p] <= AssignLetter[l,s,p];
   con LockedPrevious {l in LETTERS, s in STEPS diff {1}, p in POSITIONS}:
      IsLocked[l,s,p] <= AssignLetter[l,s-1,p];
   con LockedLater {l in LETTERS, s in STEPS diff {1}, p in POSITIONS, s2 in s+1..numSteps}:
      IsLocked[l,s,p] <= 1 - sum {p2 in POSITIONS} AssignLetter[l,s2,p2];

   /* call MILP solver */
   solve;

   /* report solution */
   str sol {STEPS, POSITIONS};
   str locked {STEPS, POSITIONS};
   for {s in STEPS} do;
      for {w in WORDS: AssignWord[w,s].sol > 0.5} do;
         for {p in 1..length(w)} sol[s,p] = char(w,p);
         leave;
      end;
      if s = 1 then continue;
      for {l in LETTERS, p in POSITIONS: IsLocked[l,s,p].sol > 0.5} do;
         locked[s,p] = l;
         leave;
      end;
   end;
   print sol;
   print locked;
   put ({l in LETTERS: UseLetter[l].sol < 0.5});
quit;


Here's one that omits X and satisfies the additional requirements from @smci:


JUMPY
 |
QUICK
  |
BLITZ
|
BADGE
    |
SHOVE
  |
FROWN



I think your "I solved this via integer linear programming" answers would be better if you also copied-and-pasted in the code that solves them. (Unless it's thousands of lines of boilerplate or something.) There would be more for interested others to learn from. Without that, it doesn't really say that much more than "obtained via thinking really hard" would.

@GarethMcCaughan I added the code to my answer.

Nice! Thank you.

Whoa! SAS code!

This is another answer without using Z. I used wildcard search with an online dictionary to search for words semi-manually but it was still very hard for me. I found multiple 24 points solution before I found this solution after many hours. I tried to exclude special terms or uncommon words. Unsure, how common the first two words are (which I didn't know myself).


 FOXED
 JIVES
 WIMPY
 RUGBY
 QUANT
 CHALK



I think the first two words are common enough (the first usually preceded by "out-").  The only word I find to be somewhat rare is your fifth.  But you gotta get that Q in there somehow...

I think a Quant is a slang for a Financial Quantitative Analysis. It's an obscure enough of a job itself that it is almost an industry specific slang.

"Quant Rating" is used on several stock trading sites.

I found "quant" in the dictionary and it looked like quantum or quanta but I didn't know it's a financial job term. Cambridge Dictionary entry Dang.
